# Using the Selectize API on non-multiple select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js, plunker

I have a simple [Selectize](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) setup where I'm trying to use it's `getOption` and `addOption` methods.

```
<select id="select">
  <option value="0">Thomas Edison</option>
  <option value="1">Nikola</option>
  <option value="3">Nikola Tesla</option>
  <option value="2">Arnold Schwarzenegger</option>
</select>
<button id="get-option">Get option</button>
<button id="add-option">Add option</button>
```

I've written some JS to call methods on my selectize instance:

```
jQuery(function() {
  var selectize = $('#select').selectize()[0].selectize;

  $('#add-option').on('click', function() {
    selectize.addOption({ text: 'Peter Pan' });
  });

  $('#get-option').on('click', function() {
    console.log('Get option:', selectize.getOption(2)[0]);
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, the `addOption` function doesn't seem to add an option to the select box. Even worse, the `getOption` call just returns `undefined`. Also, if I add `multiple` to the `<select>` tag then both API calls work as expected.

I've created [a Plunker showing the issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/eamTXqDqycrvEg6hr9l1?p=preview).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a select which isn't multiple, you use `selectize.getValue()` to retrieve the current value.

And to add an option you have to provide a value property for the option and you were providing the text property only.

So if you're just trying to get the selected value use:

```
jQuery(function() {
  var selectize = $('#select').selectize()[0].selectize;

  $('#add-option').on('click', function() {
    selectize.addOption({ value: 99, text: 'Peter Pan' });
  });

  $('#get-option').on('click', function() {
    console.log('Get option:', selectize.getValue());
  });
});
```

But in your example the attempt to get the option with value 2 seems redundant; you know the value is 2. If you can further explain what you're trying to achieve maybe I can help further.

The docs could be clearer but it's all there. https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods_options

Comment: Thanks for the help. In the second example, I was trying to get the text of the option with value 2. Regarding the docs, I found that while the descriptions of the methods were fine, there was no explanation of the differences between `value`, `option` and `item`. Perhaps the differences would be obvious to most people.